# Canvas toggle filling whole page removing scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I've got a canvas on my page and want to toggle it filling the page and backwards. My page is usually "higher" then a screens height so there is a scrollbar on my page. This scroll-bar does't hide when I'm setting the size of my canvas like that in my css:

```
canvas {
    display: inline;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 50;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}

canvas.fullscreen {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
//toggle the fullscreen mode
function fullscreen() {
    if (!fullWindowState) {
        fullWindowState = true;
        //canvas goes full Window
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.className = "fullscreen"
    } else {
        fullWindowState = false;
        //canvas goes normal
        canvas.width = 820;
        canvas.height = 600;
        canvas.className = "";
    }
}
```

The full code is on github too and the page is on gh-pages 
http://patsimm.github.io/mandelight/

I really don't know what to do to remove the scrollbar when the canvas is in "fullscreen" mode. Every help is apreciated!

Thanks!
patsimm

Comment: I see no scrollbar on latest Firefox v33.0.2

Comment: im using Firefox v33.0 and theres definately a scrollbar. Having pretty small screen on my laptop. Chrome v38.0.2125.111 has the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried applying `height: 100%; overflow:hidden` to html and body while in fullscreen mode? `(function() { var s = document.createElement("style"); s.type = "text/css"; s.textContent = "html,body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }"; document.head.appendChild(s); })();` in console seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has something to do width `<canvas>` tag.

`<canvas>` will cause scrollbar if not set to `display:block`.

detail: http://colla.me/bug/show/canvas_cannot_have_exact_size_to_fullscreen

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. link is dead though.

Comment: Genius, thank you so much :)

Comment: I am curious, why does display:inline canvas cause scroll bar?

Answer (score 8):

Try setting `overflow` to `hidden` when you're in `fullWindowState`;

```
//toggle the fullscreen mode
function fullscreen() {
    if (!fullWindowState) {
        fullWindowState = true;
        //canvas goes full Window
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.className = "fullscreen"

        document.body.scrollTop = 0; // <-- pull the page back up to the top
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // <-- relevant addition
    } else {
        fullWindowState = false;
        //canvas goes normal
        canvas.width = 820;
        canvas.height = 600;
        canvas.className = "";

        document.body.style.overflow = 'visible'; // <-- toggle back to normal mode
    }

}
```

Comment: That works for the scrollbar to disappear, thank you! But the canvas is always shown on top of the page so if you switch to fullscreen not being at the top you see half of the canvas and half of the rest of the page.

Comment: Try setting the scrollTop of the body to 0 before setting the overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following `CSS` style for `<html>` and `<body>` tags,

```
<style>
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

and the following `javascript` code to set `width` and `height` of the `<canvas id="canvas"><canvas>` element,

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go into full screen mode and use the developer tools to set `visibility: hidden` on the canvas, you can see that the page content behind the canvas is is too large, causing the scrollbars to appear. I was able to get rid of the scrollbars by setting `display: none` on the page footer. You could toggle the `display` property of the footer or other content while in full screen mode since it will be covered up by the canvas anyway.